# JS code only works on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want that my menu stays open when I refresh the page. I use cookies for that.
But it only works on IE. On chrome and firefox it isnt working.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $body = $('body'),
        $btn = $('#push-menu-toggle'),
        $menu = $('#push-menu'),
        menu_state = $.cookie('my_cookie_name'),
        viewportX = $(window).width();

    var cookieValue = $.cookie('my_cookie_name');

    if (cookieValue === 'close') {
        $body.addClass('small-menu');
    } else {
        $body.removeClass('small-menu');
    }

    $.cookie('my_cookie_name', menu_state);
    $('.cookie-is').find('em').remove();
    $('.cookie-is').prepend().html('<em>' + $.cookie('my_cookie_name') + '</em>');

    $btn.click(function () {
        $body.toggleClass('small-menu');
        $.removeCookie('my_cookie_name');

        if ($body.hasClass('small-menu')) {
            menu_state = 'close';
        } else {
            menu_state = 'open';
        }

        $.cookie('my_cookie_name', menu_state);
        $('.cookie-is').find('em').remove();
        $('.cookie-is').prepend().html('<em>' + $.cookie('my_cookie_name') + '</em>');
    });
});
```

http://codepen.io/sebastiaann/pen/KzBqEN

Comment: Some error on console?

Comment: How are you opening your files? Are you running a webserver? Do you navigate to the page using `http://127.0.0.1` or `http://localhost`?

Comment: What precisely does not work? The menu on your code pen sample site stays open with chrome 50 (50.0.2661.75) and ff 45 (45.0.2).